# How is zig zag scan carried out in sampled components in JPEG?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

A data block is 8x8 in JPEG. We zig zag scan it and then encode it using run length and huffman coding.
If a component is subsampled, that means some of the samples are going to be ignored. Does that mean that the zigzag scan is done on a 4x4, or 2x2 block? Or even 8x4 or 4x2 block?

Answer (score 1):

The next level of the Minimum Coded Unit (MCU). An MCU consists of 8x8 blocks. If you subsample components, you increase the size of the MCU and don't reduce the 8x8 block.

Comment: You mean process more data blocks? You mean we zig zag the MCU, not the data block and MCU is always 8x8?

Comment: No, an MCU might have four 8x8 blocks for Y, one 8x8 block for Cb, and one 8x8 block for Cr that represents a 16x16 area of pixels. You zigzag through each 8x8x block.

Comment: After reading your comment it dawned on me that the diagrams in the ITU-T.81 actually show data units and not individual pixels. Anyway, does this mean that when we do down sampling (e.g with chrominance) we completely throw away data units (i.e 8x8 blocks) and thus we are infact skipping whole data units rather than individual pixels? e.g with Y having 2x2 and Cr having 1x1 sampling, we take alternate Cr data units?

Comment: Could you please clarify of during subsampling we skip samples or whole data blocks instead?

Comment: If you sub sample, for every N Y component values you take M Cb and P Cr values. For all practicable purposes, N will always be greater than M and P, although the opposite is allowed. The JPEG standard does not define how this is done. You could use every other pixel or (more common) average the pixels.